# Making request to youtube data api with already existing credentials

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to make authorized requests to youtube data API to get information on a users activity and subscriptions. In my application I do the authorization flow using [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) with the [passport-youtube-v3 strategy](https://github.com/yanatan16/passport-youtube-v3). For this reason I already have authorisation tokens required for accessing a users data. For me it is not clear though how I am supposed to use the youtube API if I already have user credentials. Here's my flow and where I struggle:

1. Acquire user credentials (token) using passportjs.
2. Making a "manual" request to youtube data API using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or any other request library for that matter:

   ```
   const baseUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions";
   const opts = {
     params: {
       part: "snippet",
       mine: true,
       fields: "items(snippet(title%2C+channelId%2Cthumbnails%2Fdefault%2Furl))",
       key: youtubeAuth.clientID,
       access_token: user.youtube.token
     }
   }

   return axios.get(baseUri, opts)
     .then(response => {
       console.log(response);
     })
     .catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
     });
   ```

My key parameter looks something like this:

```
857220510254-q8pkdd9ugp2be167s5ged7ave4pqa5rn.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

And tokens look something like this

```
ya29.GlttZIaiVLxzaZDu-5-KTd5jRHhqh684Q4PFoUF3_72D9Ig0uz9CyrLwnotKMOUcnZ93kTVoYH5Bc6WCfUS1tNY5DbEMDN7nCeiUMU9vmkQWLTUAaKVS3A7XhB65
```

This doesn't seem to be the correct way of doing it since I keep getting a 401 error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "authError",
                "message": "Invalid Credentials",
                "locationType": "header",
                "location": "Authorization"
            }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Invalid Credentials"
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to do this this way or do I have to use the google SDKs as shown in the [nodejs quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your Google API call, the recommended way is using the official Google library : [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client).

You can request Youtube subscriptions with :

```
var google = require('googleapis'),
    OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

// ....

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    config.clientID,
    config.clientSecret,
    config.callbackURL
);

oauth2Client.credentials = {
    access_token: req.user.access_token,
    refresh_token: req.user.refresh_token
};

var youtube = google.youtube({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: oauth2Client
});

youtube.subscriptions.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    mine: true,
    headers: {}
}, function(err, data, response) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Here is a complete example of using [`passport-youtube-v3`](https://github.com/yanatan16/passport-youtube-v3), [`googleapis`](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) and [`mongoose`](http://mongoosejs.com/) :

```
var app = require('express')(),
    passport = require('passport'),
    YoutubeV3Strategy = require('passport-youtube-v3').Strategy,
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    google = require('googleapis'),
    OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2,
    session = require('express-session');

var config = {
    clientID: 'CLIENT_ID',
    clientSecret: 'CLIENT_SECRET',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback'
};

var db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB");

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: String, unique: true },
    access_token: String,
    refresh_token: String,
    name: String
}, { collection: "user" });

var User = db.model('User', userSchema);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new YoutubeV3Strategy({
        clientID: config.clientID,
        clientSecret: config.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: config.callbackURL,
        scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly']
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

        process.nextTick(function() {

            User.findOne({ _id: profile.id }, function(err, res) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (res) {
                    console.log("user exists");
                    return done(null, res);
                } else {
                    console.log("insert user");
                    var user = new User({
                        _id: profile.id,
                        access_token: accessToken,
                        refresh_token: refreshToken,
                        name: profile.displayName
                    });
                    user.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            return done(err);
                        return done(null, user);
                    });
                }
            })
        });
    }
));

function userLogged(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    res.redirect('/auth/google');
}

app.use(session({ secret: 'somesecret' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('youtube'));

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('youtube', {
        successRedirect: '/profile',
        failureRedirect: '/'
    }));

app.get('/profile', userLogged, function(req, res) {

    var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
        config.clientID,
        config.clientSecret,
        config.callbackURL
    );

    oauth2Client.credentials = {
        access_token: req.user.access_token,
        refresh_token: req.user.refresh_token
    };

    google.youtube({
        version: 'v3',
        auth: oauth2Client
    }).subscriptions.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        mine: true,
        headers: {}
    }, function(err, data, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error: ' + err);
            res.json({
                status: "error"
            });
        }
        if (data) {
            console.log(data);
            res.json({
                status: "ok",
                data: data
            });
        }
        if (response) {
            console.log('Status code: ' + response.statusCode);
        }
    });
});

app.listen(8080)

console.log('go to http://localhost:8080/auth/google')
```

To run this example you should have in google console :

- javascript origin : `http://localhost:8080`
- redirect URI : `http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback`

Note that you can also use [`passport-google-oauth`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth) instead of [`passport-youtube-v3`](https://github.com/yanatan16/passport-youtube-v3)